# odoo12 website/translations does not include my module

Tags: module, translation, customization, odoo-12

I struggled a LOT with the translation of my module.

As I finally get it, I share the result, hoping it will save someone some day.

My local Odoo didn't wish to translate at all my module. I tried everything, until I drop the `ir.translation` table to rewrite it from scratch, but still, it wouldn't.

When I got to odoo.sh for other tests, it miraculously appeared translated. I can't explain why. I guess a fresh start solves it and I may have had re-import translations to solve issue.
But some text stayed untranslated, and this is the most tricky part.

The widgets were not translated at all, even if portal_chatter is correclty translated and if I copied the code and translations.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is dead simple, but I had a long road to find out.
You need to add a model `ir.http`, like in `website_sales` or `website_livechat`, and make it add your module to an obscur `_get_translation_frontend_modules_domain` method.

PS : I don't if that helps, but maybe.
I also added this : 
`'js': ['static/src/js/*.js'], 'qweb': ['static/src/xml/*/*.xml']`
to my `__manifest__.py`

Comment: I must add that, even though I'm not sure it was useful, that it seems to be forbidden to organize your widgets as you wish. A standard is frozen (`xml` and `js` folders in `src/static`) in odoo/odoo/tools/translate.py at lines 988 and 994 :
`if fnmatch.fnmatch(root, '*/static/src/js*'):` and
`if fnmatch.fnmatch(root, '*/static/src/xml*'):`

Comment: Have you found solution for that ?

Comment: /lv/website/translations/b1501aebd883a6358ec20cd20823b7eccea0e6f9?mods=&lang=lv_LV
returns just couple of modules
no custom modules

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025625/320150 there I've posted a code-example for the ir.http inheritance.

Comment: Yes @RihardNovozhilov I did, the answer is the solution. Thx @OlafW for the example.
In my case (Odoo12), I added this to the `_get_translation_frontend_modules_domain` function :

`domain = super(IrHttp, cls)._get_translation_frontend_modules_domain(); return expression.OR([domain, [("name", "=", "MY_MODULE")]])`